# Bivariate distribution with normal conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, statistical-inference

Define the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ as:

$$f(x,y)\propto \exp(-1/2[Ax^2y^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-Dy]),$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are constants.

Show that the distribution of $X\mid Y=y$ is normal with mean $\frac{By+C}{Ay^2+1}$ and variance $\frac{1}{Ay^2+1}$. Derive a corresponding result for the distribution of $Y\mid X=x$.

Attempt:

I tried to integrate the equation w.r.t. $x$ in order to find $X\mid Y=y$. However, I'm not sure if I am correct:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-1/2[Ax^2y^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-Dy])\,dx$$

$$ =\left[\frac{\exp[-1/2[Ax^2y^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-Dy]}{-Axy^2-1/2+By+C}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

Whatever the value of the previous integration (call it "Q"), then we would divide the original equation by "Q", i.e.:

$$ \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{Q}$$

Which would give us $f_{X\mid Y=y}(X\mid Y=y)$.

How do I go about evaluating

$$ =\left[\frac{\exp[-1/2[Ax^2y^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-Dy]}{-Axy^2-1/2+By+C}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: You shouldn't speak of integrating with respect to $X$ if you mean integrating with respect to $x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also, you have $f_{X\mid Y=y}(X\mid Y=y)$ where you need $f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)$, with a lower-case $x$ as the argument to the function.  If you treat things like this as mere formalities, you'll be permanently confused.  Think instead about what they _mean_. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use:

$$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} =  \frac{f(x,y)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx} $$
We first note that:
$$ -0.5(Ax^2y^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-2Dy) =$$ $$ -0.5(Ay^2+1)\left(x-\frac{By+c}{Ay^2+1} \right)^2 -0.5\left(y^2-2Dy - \frac{(By+c)^2}{Ay^2+1}\right).$$
This gives us:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\rm e}^{-0.5(Ax^2y^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-2Dy) }dx$$
$$ ={\rm e}^{-0.5\left(y^2-2Dy- \frac{(By+c)^2}{Ay^2+1}\right) }\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\rm e}^{ -0.5(Ay^2+1)\left(x-\frac{By+c}{Ay^2+1} \right)^2 }dx$$
$$ = {\rm e}^{-0.5\left(y^2-2Dy- \frac{(By+c)^2}{Ay^2+1}\right) } (Ay^2+1)^{-1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\rm e}^{-0.5z^2 } dz$$ 
$$ = {\rm e}^{-0.5\left(y^2-2Dy- \frac{(By+c)^2}{Ay^2+1}\right) } (Ay^2+1)^{-1} \sqrt{2\pi}.$$

Finally:

$$ f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=y) = \frac{1}{ (Ay^2+1)^{-1}\sqrt{2\pi}} {\rm e}^{-0.5(Ay^2+1)\left(x-\frac{By+c}{Ay^2+1} \right)^2 }.$$

Comment: I think you're somewhat confused.  The function $f_{X\mid Y=y}$ should have $x$, not $y$ as its argument.  It doesn't make sense to speak of $f_{X\mid Y}(y\mid Y=y)$.  If you're conditioning on $Y=y$, then $y$ is a constant.  And at any rate you need to integrate with respect to $y$, not $x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks.Corrected a couple of x's.It should be better now.

Comment: OK, you're integrating with respect to $x$ in order to find the normalizing constant.  But that's the hard way.  That there is some normalizing constant (as opposed to the integral's being infinite) is readily seen.  If you can shoe that it's $\exp\left(\frac{-1}2\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2\right)$ plus terms not depending on $x$, then look at what functions of $y$ are $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then you've got it, without finding the normalizing constant. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

You would need to integrate out $y$, not $x$, to get a marginal density that is a function of $x$.

What you have inside of $\exp\left(\dfrac{-1}2\left(\bullet\bullet\bullet\right)\right)$ is
$$
Ax^2y^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-Dy.
$$
Think of how this behaves as a function of $x$.  You want
$$
\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2 + (\text{something not depending on $x$}).
$$
You need to figure out what $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are.  The standard method in algebra for this sort of thing is completing the square.

\begin{align}
& Ay^2x^2+x^2+y^2-2Bxy-2Cx-Dy \\[8pt]
= {} & (Ay^2+1)x^2 -2(By+C)x + \text{terms not depending on $x$} \\[8pt]
= {} & (Ay^2+1)\left(x^2 - 2\frac{By+C}{Ay^2+1} x\right) + \text{terms not depending on $x$} \\[8pt]
= {} & (Ay^2+1)\left(x^2 - 2\frac{By+C}{Ay^2+1} x + \left(\frac{By+C}{Ay^2+1}\right)^2\right) + \text{terms not depending on $x$} \\[8pt]
= {} & (Ay^2+1)\left(x - \frac{By+C}{Ay^2+1}\right)^2 + \text{terms not depending on $x$} \\[8pt]
= {} & \left(\frac{x - \frac{By+C}{Ay^2+1}}{1/\sqrt{Ay^2+1}}\right)^2 + \text{terms not depending on $x$} \\[8pt]
= {} & \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 + \text{terms not depending on $x$, if }\mu=\text{ what and }\sigma=\text{ what?}
\end{align}